# How to link multiple IDs together in R?

Tags: r, linker, ids

I have the following dataset pairs in id1 and id2 column which are all related to id 313. I am new to R and trying to find a solution that could link all those numbers to id 313. I tried using the sqldf join but does not turn out to be very effective.

```
id1<- c(313, 313, 313, 313, 313, 314, 314, 314, 314, 315, 317, 317, 317, 318, 318, 319)
id2<-c(314, 315, 316, 319, 320, 315, 316, 319, 320, 316, 318, 319, 320, 319, 320, 320)

df<-cbind.data.frame (id1, id2)
```

The desired output would look something like this.

> ```
> id1   id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7 id8
> 313   314 315 316 317 318 319 320
> ```

So basically the idea is to group them together in one row so it is regarded as one id. Greatly appreciate any suggestion that can tie them together.

Comment: Using `data.table` : `dcast(setDT(df), id1~rowid(id1), value.var = 'id2')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(
  x1 = c(df$id1, df$id2) %>% unique()
) %>% 
  mutate(
    x2 = paste0("id", row_number())
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x2, values_from = x1)
```